# ambiguity in the name of the header

Tags: header-footer, lyx, acronyms

I use Lyx 2.1, document class : report.
I created a chapter called "list of acronyms" after "list of tables".
At the 2nd page of the chapter "list of acronyms" header is incorrect.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try `\cleardoublepage` directly after `\listoftables`

Comment: the problem persists

Comment: along with the `\cleardoublepage`, put a blank line before and after it to ensure vertical mode.  (not tested.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are using a starred chapter command `\chapter*{}` no header mark gets set. Therefore, LaTeX does not know, what to write and uses the previous header text. You will have to tell the starred chapter or section the header-title as follows.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass[french ]{report}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\listoftables
%
%\cleardoublepage % shows no effect
%
\chapter*{chapter1}
\markboth{chapter1}{%section1
}
\blindtext[5]
\end{document}
```