# Chapter header always get's a numeric prefix, even with \chapter*{}

Tags: sectioning, header-footer, numbering, chapters

The following minimal working example explains best my issue with my current 150 page strong thesis:

```
\documentclass{book}
\begin{document}
  \chapter{Lorem}
    Lorem. \newpage Lorem.
  \chapter*{Ipsum}
    \chaptermark{Ipsum}
    Ipsum. \newpage Ipsum.
\end{document}
```

**Chapter 1: Lorum** is correct, as it is on the header on page two (after `\newpage`). But the header on page four says, **Chapter 1: Ipsum**. But that does not belong to chapter 1 anymore and my desire when using `chapter*{}` is to remove numeric references everywhere, even in header. How can I achieve this?

Comment: `\chapter*` does not add numbers, does not write to the TOC and DOES NOT clear the header. Try adding `\markboth{}{}` after `\chapter*` to clear it

Comment: No visible effect. I'm aware that `\chapter*` does not do TOC and HEAD stuff. That's why I use `\chaptermark` however, things like Table of Contents or References which seem to behave like this do not get a `Chapter 1:` prefix. How to remove this?

Comment: Don't use `\chaptermark` use `\markboth{Ipsum}{Ipsum}`. `\chaptermark{text}` is a front end for `\markboth` and it adds the chapter data to the `text`

Comment: `\markboth{Ipsum}{Ipsum}` did the trick, thanks!

Comment: I'll write an answer

Comment: this answer provides much the same information: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/187228/579

Comment: @barbarabeeton that question does not mention `\chaptermark` at all, the rest is related.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is the use of `\chaptermark`, among other things this adds the **Chapter 1** prefix to the title given to the header data.

Instead manually use the macro that `\chaptermark` feeds data to, namely

```
\markboth{Ipsum}{Ipsum}
```

Actually, it only feeds data to the first argument and leaves the other empty, I just prefer to clear both headers this way just in case.